# Make autocomplete="tel-national" work in Safari

Tags: autocomplete, safari, autofill, tel

I have a phone field which should autofill if that's enabled in the browser.
I need the country code to be stripped and only display the rest of the phone number.

That's usually achieved with autocomplete="tel-national" which works fine in Chrome but I can't make it work in Safari 10.
autocomplete="tel-country-code" or other tel related tokens don't work either.

I also used this form which should be a cross-browser autofill form, but it fails to fill in correctly using Safari:
https://codepen.io/grigs/pen/NNVZPZ

```html
<label for="tel-national">Telephone number without the county code</label>
  <input type="text" name="tel-national" id="tel-national" autocomplete="home tel-national">
```

Do you have any solution for this? Or maybe an alternative for achieving the same result?